# Cannot save new row in database because of OleDbException using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb, oledbexception

As the title states, I am having a problem and I cannot find it's cause.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Register
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim strProvider As String
    Dim strDataSource As String
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        Me.Close()
        SRS_Main_Menu.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        strDataSource = "Data Source = C:\Users\WORK\Documents\vb.net db files\questionThreeDB1.mdb"
        strProvider = "PROVIDER= Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;"
        con.ConnectionString = strProvider & strDataSource
        tables = ds.Tables
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM questionThreeTbl"
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "Students")
        Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Students").NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item(1) = txtId.Text()
        dsNewRow.Item(2) = txtName.Text()
        dsNewRow.Item(3) = txtSurname.Text()
        dsNewRow.Item(4) = txtCellNum.Text()
        dsNewRow.Item(5) = txtParCell.Text()
        dsNewRow.Item(6) = txtAddress.Text()

        ds.Tables("Students").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "Students")

        MsgBox("New Student Record Saved")
        Me.Close()
        SRS_Main_Menu.Show()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically when I select the submit button the error pops up pointing to the line:

```
da.Update(ds, "Students")
```

It states that there is a problem with my INSERT INTO statement.
Any clues as to what is going on here?

Comment: Read the error message - it tells you what is wrong. There is no SQL INSERT there, so that might be the problem.  You could try getting the INSERT command from that command builder

Comment: @Plutonix How would I go about applying that?

Comment: `da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand`  If you do that when you first build the dataadapter, you dont have to do it ever again.  You probably ought not be using a single global connection either